# Is 中文亲属名称 the correct translation for "Family member names in Chinese"(i.e. as in regard to one's family tree)?

Tags: translation

Is 中文亲属名称 the correct translation for "Family member names in Chinese"(i.e. as in regard to one's family tree)? Anyone has a better translation?

Comment: websearch using  "中文亲属名称" or  "亲戚中文名称"  will supply the commonly used formulations (the above among them)

Answer (score 1):

In Chinese, understanding the context is the important part. Family Members can means direct family members which means 亲属 or 家属, or including all the relatives (亲戚 or 家眷), but since you are referring to the context of family tree, 家族成员 should be used.

Answer (score 1):

A possible translation is 家庭成员的汉语姓名.

It seems to me that *Family member names in Chinese* looks really like a section title on some form to be filled.